# Oracle: SELECT statement GROUP BY clause

Tags: oracle

I'm working with a table with structure like the following: (not my design, can't be changed)

```
Columns:    foreign_key    job_type    job_code
            1              1           AA
            1              2           BB
            2              1           
            2              2           CC
```

Values in job_type can only be 1 or 2. Values in job_code can be any varchar.

I'm trying to get rows from this table in the following order:

```
            foreign_key    job_type_1_code    job_type_2_code
```

My search query is like this:

```
select foreign_key
from my_table
    where
    ( job_type = 1 and job_code like 'D%'
      or
      job_type = 2 and job_code like 'in_job_2_code%'
    )
group by foreign_key
```

The problem I have is that this returns job_code BB and CC when I'm expecting no results at all.
How can I group these together so that the query will not return any result?

Comment: You need to use a [Pivot](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query works if you always have records for both job types:

```
SELECT a.foreign_key, a.job_code as job_type_1_code, b.job_code as job_type_2_code,
FROM table_name a INNER JOIN table_name b ON a.foreign_key = b.foreign_key 
    AND a.job_type = 1 AND b.job_type = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use **CASE** statement not Group by

```
select foreign_key, 
 case job_type when 1 then job_code else null end as job_type_1_code,
 case job_type when 2 then job_code else null end as job_type_2_code
from your_table
```